# rails redirect_to error No route matches

Tags: ruby, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I'm trying to redirect to login page or root page

```
redirect_to new_user_session_path, :alert => exception.message
redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
```

but both are returning an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
```

when I do the rake routes there is a root path and a new_user_session (made with devise)

the routes.rb has

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
root 'home#index'
```

If I do a

```
redirect_to '/', :alert => exception.message
```

it works and goes to the home#index, but if I try with

```
redirect_to '/login', :alert => exception.message
```

then it says `localhost not working, localhost redirected too much times`

The redirection is in the application_controller.rb inside a catch exception for denied access in cancan

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to '/', :alert => exception.message
end
```

**Edit: Solution**

if I write `main_app.` before the path it works so `main_app.new_user_session_path` and `main_app.root_path` works fine.
I've always done it without the main_app and it used to work, I'm not sure why now I need the main_app before the path, but it works.

Comment: try with `root_url` and `new_user_session_url` instead

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still the same result